# if else not working properly in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing calculation using if else in Javascript.

Below is HTML:

```
 <b>Select Number of Rooms:</b>
            <select name="rooms" id="room" required>
            <option value="8">Rooms</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            </select><br><br>
            <div id="paxx">

            <div id="first">
            <b>Room 1 - Adult:</b>
            <select name="Adults" id="Adult" required>

            <option value="0">Adult</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>

            </select><br><br>
            </div>
            <div id="firsts">
            <b>Room 1 - Child:</b>
            <select name="child" id="child">
            <option value="0">Child</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            </select><br><br>
            </div>
            <div id="Adt1">
            <b>Room 2 - Adult:</b>
            <select name="Adult1" id="Adult1">
            <option value="0">Adult</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            </select><br><br>
            </div>
            <div id="chd1">
            <b>Room 2 - Child:</b>
            <select name="child1" id="child1">
            <option value="0">Child</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            </select><br><br>
            </div>
            <div id="Adt2">
            <b>Room 3 - Adult:</b>
            <select name="Adult2" id="Adult2">
            <option value="0">Adult</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            </select><br><br>
            </div>
            <div id="chd2">
            <b>Room 3 - Child:</b>
            <select name="child2" id="child2">
            <option value="0">Child</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            </select><br><br>
            </div>
            <div id="Adt3">
            <b>Room 4 - Adult:</b>
            <select name="Adult3" id="Adult3">
            <option value="0">Adult</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            </select><br><br>
            </div>
            <div id="chd3">
            <b>Room 4 - Child:</b>
            <select name="child3" id="child3">
            <option value="0">Child</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            </select><br><br>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Javascript portion is as below:

```
    <script>
    $("#paxx").change(function(){
    <?php $single =  $row['single']; ?>
    var single = "<?php  echo $single; ?>";
    <?php $double =  $row['doubl']; ?>
    var doubl = "<?php  echo $double; ?>";
    var price = "";

    var $sumDisplay = $('#total');
    var t1 = parseInt($("#Adult").val());  
    var t2 = parseInt($("#Adult1").val()); 
    var t3 = parseInt($("#Adult2").val()); 
    var t4 = parseInt($("#Adult3").val());
    var t5 = parseInt($("#child").val());
    var t6 = parseInt($("#child1").val());
    var t7 = parseInt($("#child2").val());
    var t8 = parseInt($("#child3").val());



    {

    if(parseInt($("#Adult").val()) == 1 || parseInt($("#Adult1").val()) == 1 || parseInt($("#Adult3").val()) == 1 || parseInt($("#Adult2").val()) == 1)
    {
        var total2 = t1 + t2 + t3 + t4;
        var price =  total2 * single;

    }



    if(parseInt($("#Adult").val()) == 2 || parseInt($("#Adult1").val()) == 2 || parseInt($("#Adult3").val()) == 2 || parseInt($("#Adult2").val()) == 2)
    {
        var total12 = t1 + t2 + t3 + t4;
        var price =  total12 * doubl;

    }



    if(parseInt($("#Adult").val()) == 3 || parseInt($("#Adult2").val()) == 3 || parseInt($("#Adult3").val()) == 3 || parseInt($("#Adult1").val()) == 3)
    {
        var total21 = t1 + t2 + t3 + t4;
        var price =  total21 * doubl;
    }



    if(parseInt($("#Adult").val()) == 1 && parseInt($("#child").val()) == 1 )
    {   
        var total2 = t1 + t5 ;
        var price =  total2 * doubl;

    }

}

    $sumDisplay.text(price);



});
            </script>
```

**Now issue** is when I select 1 adult and 1 child in first room it gives me correct price. And when I add another room and add 1 pax it gives me price as

3 * doubl;

But if you look at my if conditions it should work like this

2 * doubl + 1*single;

It adds another person in last if statement and does not look at first if statement when 1 person is added in the second room.

Please check and kindly suggest me a solution and point out issues if there is any.

Comment: There are 4 if statements. I can not see any else out there

Comment: a) What errors are you getting and b) post the rendered HTML. We don't need the PHP.

Comment: Please note that `parseInt` needs to be passed the radix as well, otherwise the results will be unexpected: `parseInt(n, 10)`. I am not saying this is the issue, but it is worth being safe.

Comment: @j08691 i am getting wrong calculation. Everything is working but give wrong calculation

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to help but frankly I can't figure out how exactly you're trying to calculate your prices. You're only using one of the child fields to calculate prices for your fourth case, which is only true when you have one Adult and one Child in room one. If you could explain the pricing structure that you're trying to abstract with this code, I might better be able to tell you where you're going wrong.

For one example, your third case states that effectively, if there are three adults in any one room, then the total price should be equal to the sum of all all adults in all four rooms times two. If I'm not mistaken, if you have a single adult in rooms one, two, and three, and three adults in room 4, the total price will be equal to what you'd pay for twelve adults (12 X 2), regardless of the number of children.

Comment: When I add 1 child and 1 adult in Room 1 this if should trigger

if(parseInt($("#Adult").val()) == 1 && parseInt($("#child").val()) == 1 )
 { 
  var total2 = t1 + t5 ;
  var price =  total2 * doubl;

 }


But when I add another room and add 1 person then it should trigger 1st IF

Comment: I think you need to abandon the structure you have now and explain to us what the pricing schedule is. A better structure would probably be to loop through each room, calculate the price for room based on the number of adults / children in each room, add that to a running total, and then calculate your eventual discounts based on the total rooms occupied. Otherwise it looks like you're going to need a lot more if else statements than you have. What if there is one Adult and three Children in room 4?

Comment: Pricing schedule:

If 1 person in a room then single price will be charged
If 2 or 3 pax (1 adult and 2 child or 2 adult and 1 child) then double price will be charged (num of pax * double)